# Authelia + Jellyfin + Swag (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jellyfin

I have been battling with opening my jellyfin local container to the internet while securing it through Authelia (for 2FA). I have a docker container for swag (nginx), authelia and jellyfin, all named the same way.

I used the [sample subdomain configuration from swag for Jellyfin](https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs/blob/master/jellyfin.subdomain.conf.sample) and added the authelia import to redirect through authelia before jellyfin. Authelia works fine with other services on the server.

If I take away the authelia include line in the jellyfin configuration I reach jellyfin on https://jellyfin.myserver.com without problem.

If I have authelia active, I get without problem to authelia login page through https://jellyfin.myserver.com but after I pass the authelia check I get an error 500 from Nginx.

I couldn't see relevant events in the log so I travel a little blind here.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Here is my jellyfin.subdomain.conf:

```
## Version 2023/05/31
# make sure that your jellyfin container is named jellyfin
# make sure that your dns has a cname set for jellyfin
# if jellyfin is running in bridge mode and the container is named "jellyfin", the below config should work a
s is
# if not, replace the line "set $upstream_app jellyfin;" with "set $upstream_app <containername>;"
# or "set $upstream_app <HOSTIP>;" for host mode, HOSTIP being the IP address of jellyfin
# in jellyfin settings, under "Advanced/Networking" add subdomain.mydomain.tld as a known proxy

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name jellyfin.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        # enable for Authelia (requires authelia-server.conf in the server block)
        include /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf;

        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app jellyfin;
        set $upstream_port 8096;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

        proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
        proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
    }

    location ~ (/jellyfin)?/socket {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app jellyfin;
        set $upstream_port 8096;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}
```

And the authelia.conf:

```
## Version 2023/02/09 - Changelog: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag/commits/master/root/defaults/nginx/authelia-location.conf.sample
# Make sure that your authelia container is in the same user defined bridge network and is named authelia
# Rename /config/nginx/proxy-confs/authelia.conf.sample to /config/nginx/proxy-confs/authelia.conf
# Make sure that the authelia configuration.yml has 'path: "authelia"' defined

## Send a subrequest to Authelia to verify if the user is authenticated and has permission to access the resource.
auth_request /authelia/api/verify;
## If the subreqest returns 200 pass to the backend, if the subrequest returns 401 redirect to the portal.
error_page 401 = @authelia_proxy_signin;

## Translate response headers from Authelia into variables
auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_remote_user;
auth_request_set $groups $upstream_http_remote_groups;
auth_request_set $name $upstream_http_remote_name;
auth_request_set $email $upstream_http_remote_email;
auth_request_set $authorization $upstream_http_authorization;
auth_request_set $proxy_authorization $upstream_http_proxy_authorization;

## Inject the response header variables into the request made to the actual upstream
proxy_set_header Remote-User $user;
proxy_set_header Remote-Groups $groups;
proxy_set_header Remote-Name $name;
proxy_set_header Remote-Email $email;
proxy_set_header Authorization $authorization;
proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization $proxy_authorization;

## Include the Set-Cookie header if present.
auth_request_set $set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
add_header Set-Cookie $set_cookie;
```

and proxy.conf:

```
## Version 2023/02/09 - Changelog: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag/commits/master/root/defaults/nginx/proxy.conf.sample

# Timeout if the real server is dead
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

# Proxy Connection Settings
proxy_buffers 32 4k;
proxy_connect_timeout 240;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_read_timeout 240;
proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
proxy_send_timeout 240;

# Proxy Cache and Cookie Settings
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
#proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure"; # enable at your own risk, may break certain apps
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;

# Proxy Header Settings
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Method $request_method;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;
proxy_set_header X-Original-Method $request_method;
proxy_set_header X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;" is missing in the server block in jellyfin.subdomain.conf. This should be added in somewhere above the location block as shown in [LinuxServer's blog post](https://www.linuxserver.io/blog/2020-08-26-setting-up-authelia#enabling-authelia-in-swag).

```
server {
    [server block code]

    include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;

    location / {
        [location block code]

        include /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf;
```

It may also be prudent to double check the Docker networks. The easiest solution for SWAG to work seamlessly is to have any SWAG-managed containers on the same network as the SWAG container as explained on the [SWAG GitHub](https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs#ensure-you-have-a-custom-docker-network). Since SWAG uses the container names as DNS hostnames by default, it won't be able to find your container on a separate network unless you modify the configuration to include the server's IP address.